# How do you properly escape json to be sent over ajax? (Using Datatables)

Tags: ajax, json, escaping, datatables, server-side

I would like to know how to properly escape my json code. I am using the datatables plugin and this is the json that is failing.

```
        "6\\\\\\\' 5\\\\\\\" Ford HD ",
```

It originally looks like this (without the opening/closing brackets and the comma):

```
         6\\\' 5\\\" Ford HD
```

How would I properly escape this?

Comment: that looks abuot right. what's your issues with this?

Comment: Just use one of the libary on http://www.json.org/ which will create json string from your data for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not escape the ' character. So the correct JSON will be

```
"6\\\\\\' 5\\\\\\\" Ford HD "
```

A good place where you can validate your data is http://www.jsonlint.com/.